# text file split based on regular expressions

Tags: bash, text

How can i split (in a linux commandline-bash environment) a text file into multiple text files based on a reg expression where expression is a part of a line? Example:

original.txt:

```
1,Johnny good,91240,*****
2,Joe non-frequent,34755,***
4,Mary bad credit,92323,*
2,Joe2 non-frequentsd,34755,***
223,Joe3 frequentsd,34755,***
```

Files after split:

91240.txt:

```
1,Johnny good,91240,*****
```

34755.txt:

```
2,Joe non-frequent,34755,***
2,Joe2 non-frequentsd,34755,***
223,Joe3 frequentsd,34755,***
```

92323.txt:

```
4,Mary bad credit,92323,*
```

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F, '{print >$3".txt"}' your_file
```

Comment: If I recall, some implementation of awk make you write `awk -F, {file=$3".txt"; print >file}'`

Answer (score 0):

*Try this..*

```
var=`awk -F, '{print $3}' input.txt`;
for word in $var
do
    echo $word
    grp="grep $word input.txt"
    out=$($grp);
    echo $out > "$word.txt"
done
```